# When referencing associations in the Java object model, what is the relevance behind assigning the reference a value of null?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm

I am reading a book on Hibernate which is trying to illustrate a *one-to-one* association. They are using the example of a car and an engine. Let us assume that a car can only have one engine, and one engine can go only into one type of car. The way they have shown this being implemented as Java objects, is as follows:
[image]

What is the significance behind referencing the engine class in the Car class as:  `private Engine engine;` yet referencing the Car class in the Engine class as `private Car car = null;`

Why is one being assigned the value of null, and the other is being simply declared? What is the reasoning behind this? Is this implying directionality, or the fact that the engine is a composition?

Comment: Sidenote: Please add code as code, not as image.

Comment: An engine may or may not be installed in a car when it is created . On the other hand a car will always have an engine when it is created

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, `Car car;` is the same as `Car car = null;`. In the two cases, `car` has the value of `null`. Therefore, you can interchange those and it will not affect your program.

However, not setting `engine` but setting `car` to `null` might make a *little* more sense to *some* people.

The possibility of an engine not connected to a car is higher than the possibility of a car having no engine. So I guess it just wants to emphasize that point.

But for programmers like me, they will just mentally replace all `Engine engine;` with `Engine engine = null;`.